# ruby sql server adapter issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby-1.8.7

I am attempting to port a legacy ruby code version, like 1.8x, from a server running SQL SERVER 2008R2 to one running SS 2012.

I get the following error:

```
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  Currently, only 2000, 2005, and 2008 are supported.
  C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:192:in `initialize'
```

I am not able to update the ruby code itself, although I might be able to update the sql server adapter within the ruby code base.

I cannot change to a more recent version of the ruby environment because the production code runs on Mongrel.

I am not a ruby programmer, but a .net programmer supporting ruby apps while we replace them.  I am trying to create a development environment because we haven't had one.

I am open to suggestions.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem within the constraints I have?

Comment: Look at the github repo for [mongrel](https://github.com/mongrel/mongrel). You're trying to use a version of SQL Server that didn't exist when mongrel was last updated (nearly a decade ago, when it was abandoned). Suggestion? Revert to SQL Server 2008 and hurry up with your port to .NET.

Comment: I think we are going for the 2008R2 installation because it is the dev server and is essentially my sandbox where my toys are kept.

:-)